# What is included in Springer 'Accesses'?

Tags: publishers, springer

What kind of accesses are included in the Springer 'Accesses' number?

Opening the Abstract Page / Opening Full Text HTML / Downloading Full Text PDF / Opening Full Text SharedIt Link

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Springer website](https://www.springeropen.com/get-published/indexing-archiving-and-access-to-data/article-metrics):

> Access counts - The number of times an article has been accessed on SpringerOpen or BioMed Central and SpringerLink.